# QT/QML how works mapReady on a map?

Tags: qt, qml, qtlocation

I'm stuck on the way mapReady works into QML.

According to the doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#mapReady-prop, it's advised to use the signal emitted for this property in place of Component.onCompleted

From this simple main.qml code

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    Item{
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "bboxObj"

        Map {
            anchors.fill: parent
            id: map
            plugin: Plugin{name: "osm"}
            zoomLevel: (maximumZoomLevel - minimumZoomLevel)/2
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        }

        Component.onCompleted:{
            console.log("mapReady : " + map.mapReady)
            console.log("visibleRegion : " + map.visibleRegion.boundingGeoRectangle())
        }

    }

}
```

The results is :

> ```
> qml: mapReady : false
> qml: visibleRegion : QGeoRectangle({nan, nan}, {nan, nan})
> ```

How use this onMapReady to invoke visibleRegion after the map is ready ?

I have tried this, without success :

```
Map.onMapReadyChanged: {
    console.log("mapReady : " + map.mapReady)
    console.log("visibleRegion : " + map.visibleRegion.boundingGeoRectangle())
    console.log("visibleRegion.isValid : " + map.visibleRegion.isValid)
    console.log("visibleRegion.isEmpty : " + map.visibleRegion.isEmpty)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't use Map.onMapReadyChanged, but only onMapReadyChanged inside the Map element

Comment: Thanks Paul, it's really better now !